# SAP HANA | TRUNCATE PARTITION

Tags: partitioning, hana

Is there a way we can truncate partition in SAP HANA? As official documents only say about dropping partition?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is correct on this topic. Table partitions can be dropped and re-created but not TRUNCATEd.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all data from specific partition of table is possible

Syntax : truncate table <table_name> partition <partition_name>

Except : You cannot use truncate table <table_name> partition <partition_name> when the table object is marked for replication and is created using hash- or round-robin-based partitions. Doing so will end up in error.

Check official document by SAP : https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.3/en-US/ab461944bc2b1014bc78d29ab3759f49.html